# How to change values in the model?

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to change the database values based on databse value?
For example in my DB I want to replace values 0 and 1 with inactive, active.

I could do this in the controller or view but is there a way to do this in the model so I get all the data when using for example $this->Model->find("all") ?

Comment: Can you pls put some example to clarify your question?

Comment: You could create a view helper, and then wrap your output in it to yield “friendly” names, i.e. `$this->Boolean->activeInactive($data['MyModel']['active']);`

Answer (score 0):

You  can use  the [after find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) method

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

    foreach ($results as &$result) {
        $result[$this->alias]['active'] = ($result[$this->alias]['active'] == 0) ? 'inactive' : 'active';
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I think you should test if `$result[$this->alias]['active']` is actually set. Not all queries on that model are guaranteed to return than field and you will generate warnings and also create a fake unrequested value

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Bean already said in a comment, a helper would be the proper place. I doubt you *always* want to convert the result of the find to a string. A boolean value is commonly used in a checkbox or radio button as well, so when you write to the DB you would have to convert it back.

```
public function boolToString($value) {
    if ($value == 1) {
        return __('Yes');
    }
    return __('No');
}
```

Then simply do:

```
echo $this->MyHelper->boolToString($record['Model']['field']);
```

Note that the helper method will also make sure the string is translated.